# Angular: how to render line breaks in a string inside curly braces?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Maybe this is not possible but I wonder if I can embed a line break in a string I pass to MatDialogComponent displayed on a form via `{{ }}`

I designed a simple `WarningDialogComponent` that has params for title, message, OK and cancel button text.

The message text is displayed inside the template

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    {{message}}
</mat-dialog-content>
```

This works fine except if I want the message to be have defined line breaks, something like:

> You are about to delete account 'Electricians'
>
> This cannot be undone!

I tried  using backtic quotes, or `\n\n` embedded in `message` and I know html is normally escaped. Of course I could redesign my form, or instruct it to render embedded html, but was hoping there is a simple way to somehow put a line break in the string  contained in the `message` variable that would work without a having to tinker with the component itself.

Comment: try use two variables: message and description, when description will be optional. Then html will look like 
`<mat-dialog-content>
    {{message}}
    <p *ngIf='description'>{{description}}</p>
</mat-dialog-content>`

Comment: Yes that would work, but it would involve changing the interface to the dialog to add. a "description" param, as well as changing the template.   I was just wondering if there is a way to just embed a chr(13) in the string or something.  But I can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do some **css** stuff. mat-dialog-content element automatically gets the **mat-dialog-content** class. Simply add this style to this class in your global stylesheet

```
.mat-dialog-content{white-space:pre;}
```

Now your **\n** shall be considered as **new line** in your plain text. Please refer this simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eczgmi).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like what you are looking to do is embed html in your variable and have angular display that html without sanitizing it. so that your your `{{message}}` could have line breaks `<br/>` and have them rendered in the message.

by default Angular sanitizes the contents of variables to prevent cross site scripting.

however, if the value you wish to display is 'trusted' (i.e. it isn't one that a user can enter), angular allows you to use the [Dom sanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to mark content as safe.

by using this you can have your `message` contain HTML and have it rendered as you would expect. however, for anything that you are looking to bypass the Angular sanitizer with, be sure you control where that message is coming from

Comment: Yep, I thought about playing with the santizer, but since the component is a general purpose "warning dialog" box which might incorporate user generated string in the message in some implementation in the future it seems not worth it.  Sounds like the short answer is that there's no way to incorporate a lf/cr type thing into a string in angular in a way that will display it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could use innerHTML property instead curly braces. Then you can use the tag `<br/>`

```
<mat-dialog-content [innerHTML]="message"></mat-dialog-content>
```